# Авто изменение высоты textarea при вводе текста

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть у кого-нибудь хороший вариант кода?
Вот этот

---

```
    <script>
// функция подсчета количества строк
function countLines(strtocount, cols) {
var hard_lines = 1;
var last = 0;
while ( true ) {
last = strtocount.indexOf("\n", last+1);
hard_lines ++;
if ( hard_lines == 5) break; 
if ( last == -1 ) break;
}
var soft_lines = Math.ceil(strtocount.length / (cols-1));
var hard = eval("hard_lines " + unescape("%3e") + "soft_lines;");
if ( hard ) soft_lines = hard_lines;
return soft_lines;
}
// функция вызывается при каждом нажатии клавиши в области ввода текста
function ResizeTextArea(the_form,min_rows) {
the_form.rows = Math.max(min_rows,countLines(the_form.value,the_form.cols) +1);
}
    </script>
```

---

не супер.
Почему-то из-за этого кода перестает работать этот

---

```
<script>
(function($){

    /* использование: <a class='scrollTop' href='#' style='display:none;'></a>
    ------------------------------------------------- */
    $(function(){
        var e = $(".scrollTop");
        var speed = 500;

        e.click(function(){
            $("html:not(:animated)" +( !$.browser.opera ? ",body:not(:animated)" : "")).animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 500 );
            return false; //важно!
        });
        //появление
        function show_scrollTop(){
            ( $(window).scrollTop()>300 ) ? e.fadeIn(600) : e.hide();
        }
        $(window).scroll( function(){show_scrollTop()} ); show_scrollTop();
    });

})(jQuery)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать плагин [textarea autoresize](http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/forms/textarea-autoresize.html)

Comment: Не работает у меня данный плагин.

Answer (score 1):

замените textarea на:

```css
div {
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  background-color: #FFFA98;
  border: #AAA 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```